# set initial color in jquery palette color picker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I am using the following js plugin:

https://github.com/carloscabo/jquery-palette-color-picker

The default color state when initialized is the color swatch icon. However, I would like to set the initial color to be of my choosing via jquery.

Is this possible in this plugin?

EXAMPLE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="UNIQUE_NAME"]').paletteColorPicker();
});
```

On page load will look something like this:

[image: Default view on load]

But I would like it to start out like this:

[image: Initialize color on load]

Is there something I can write that is something like this?

```
$('[name="UNIQUE_NAME"]').paletteColorPicker('#ff77b');
```

Comment: Please provide us with an example of your code, and explain what you actually need to achieve, so that we can offer you some help!

Comment: sure, I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your input elements `value` property. So if you've used this code to set up your palette picker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#your-input-element").paletteColorPicker({
    colors: [
      { "primary": "#E91E63" },
      { "primary_dark": "#C2185B" },
      { "primary_light": "#F8BBD0" },
      { "accent": "#CDDC39" },
      { "primary_text": "#212121" },
      { "secondary_text": "#727272" },
      { "divider": "#B6B6B6" }
    ],
  });
});
```

You could default to `primary_dark` by setting it in your HTML like this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="your-input-element"
  name="whatever"
  value="primary_dark"
/>
```

If you're not using objects, but providing an array of strings as palette, you can set it to one of those strings.